# Playframework does not log to file

Tags: file, logging, playframework

I keep receiving error messages like

```
This exception has been logged with id 6963fe42m
```

the default logging to the console is chopped off with the usual

```
... 10 more
```

but Play would not log to file with my application.conf containing:

```
%dev.application.log.path=./logs/log.txt
%dev.application.log.system.out=off
```

I'm running the app in dev mode.

Answer (score 1):

1. %dev... in your app denote a "dev" id, not "dev" mode. So you need to run your app using `play run --%dev`
2. you can any how get the log file if you type `play start`. It will be default logged to logs/system.out

Comment: Thanks a lot, the "start" option is a quick solution!